# Confused about linearity of wave equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Currently in a QM class. My understanding is as follows:

1. the schrodinger equation specifies solutions to your system.
2. When we solve it we get a set of wave functions, which form a basis over the function space.
3. Linear combinations of wave functions are also solutions to the wave function.

My confusion is as follows: if you can take linear combinations of your wave functions to create any arbitrary function, shouldn't this satisfy the wave equation as well? Wouldn't this make the wave equation functionally arbitrary?

Comment: Re. "take linear combinations of your wave functions to create any arbitrary function"  This would only work if "your wave functions" form a orthogonal basis for the space that contains your "arbitrary function".

Comment: Linear combinations of stationary eigenfunctions can match any starting configuration. But each propagates differently in time, and so the starting linear combinations evolve in highly restricted ways in order to satisfy the TDSE. Try a simple example.

Comment: Schrodinger's equation specify time evolution of wave function. It can not produce wave functions out of nowhere. You have to have wave function at one time. Schrodinger's equation tells us all the possible wave functions. It's like Newton's equation, you have to have initial condition to predict results .